# Codeigniter Mysql Query is not performed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a simple search engine that looks for data from database and show them up, but I can't figure why the queries are performed here is my code :

### Model Page

```
class Reference_model extends CI_Model{


        function search($match){
            $this->db->where('sReference', $match);
            $this->db->like('nReference', $match);
            $this->db->or_like('sSearch', $match);
            $this->db->from('treference', $match);
            $query = $this->db->get();

                if($query->num_rows > 0){
                    $output = '<ul>';
                    foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
                        $output .= '<li>'.$rows->nReference.'</li>';
                    }
                    $output .='</ul>';
                }else{
                    return "<p>No Results!</p>"; //No Results!
                }
                return $output;
    }
}
```

### Controller Page

```
class References extends CI_Controller {


    function index()
    {   
        $q = $this->input->post('q');
        $this->load->model('Reference_model');
        $results['result'] = $this->Reference_model->search($q);


        $this->load->view('constants/header');
        $this->load->view('references',$results);
        $this->load->view('constants/footer');

}
}
```

when I perform the search from the search form I get the **No Results!**, can some one help me out, because I've tried with many times without, and I'm not a professional webdeveloper I'm just learning, thank all the contributors

Comment: Check what was the query by.  $this->db->last_query()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model :**

```
    class Reference_model extends CI_Model
    {


        function search($match)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');   //this line
            $this->db->where('sReference', $match);
            $this->db->like('nReference', $match);
            $this->db->or_like('sSearch', $match);
            $this->db->from('treference');  //this line
            $query = $this->db->get();

                if($query->num_rows > 0){
                    $output = '<ul>';
                    foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
                        $output .= '<li>'.$rows->nReference.'</li>';
                    }
                    $output .='</ul>';
                }else{
                    return "<p>No Results!</p>"; //No Results!
                }
                return $output;
        }
    }
```

Try to debug your query with **echo /print_r**  OR  **echo $this->db->last_query();**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i believe this should do it. another problem he has and that no one mentioned is the order of his query lines. i believe the order needs to be from top to bottom starting with the `select` line on top

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->like('sReference', $match);
$this->db->like('nReference', $match);
$this->db->or_like('sSearch', $match);
```

and this part

```
$this->db->from('treference', $match);
```

change it to

```
$this->db->from('treference');
```

try this..

hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if($query->num_rows > 0){
```

to

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
```

The `num_rows` should be a function.
If still doesnt work.
Try to dump the query being  generated and post it here.

```
var_dump($this->db->last_query()); die('x'); if($query->num_rows > 0){
```